# The name or security ID (SID) of the domain specified is inconsistent with the trust information for that domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain, virtual-machines

When logging into a new virtual machine which was recently added to a domain, I am getting the following error message:

**The system cannot log you on due to the following error:
The name or security ID (SID) of the domain specified is inconsistent with the trust information for that domain.
Please try again or consult your system administrator.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or use [New SID](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897418.aspx) tool from Microsoft Sysinternals to generate a new SID.

Comment: Since this was a cloned Virtual Machine, the New SID tool did the trick.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Did you clone the machine w/o using sysprep (or some other tool that can clear SIDs)? If you did I would rebuild the box. If you didn't a simple remove from domain, then readd to domain should clear that up.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, NewSID has been depreciated.

Any other way except for SysPrep?